Maven Properties referring to itself
It is allowed to have a Maven property of the following form?
<prop>${prop}</prop>

Unfortunately this is not in my Pom, so I cannot change it. Then the Maven Model Builder throws Null Pointer Exceptions at the point where it tries to parse the property. If this entry is removed, parsing works and it keeps the string "${prop}" wherever the property is used.
Apparently the developers of the pom must have had a reason, why they added this entry in the first place. I presume it is somehow to make sure that the build fails if this property does not exist.
However this makes resolving the poms quite challenging if I have this as a transitive dependency.
Is this allowed according to Maven ? If yes, then I will report a bug, if no I have to deal with it somehow.
I could not find a detailed specification for Maven-Properties.

It is unclear what is the use case. How do you got that property that you are saying it is not in your pom? Also add a [mre].

Then the Maven Model Builder throws Null Pointer Exceptions at the point where it tries to parse the propert what kind of project is this? If you can remove it so it's your own? It's bit puzzling? Please more detailed explanations...

Is it possible creator want to force user to define this property before using that module?

Maybe the original pom authors wanted to enforce that the property is specified via a java system property on the start of mvn, like with mvn package -Dprop=foobar ?

The pom in which the property is defined as above is not my own. Parsing it programmatically fails with a Null-Pointer-Exception. I can of course copy their pom, create a test-case out of it and in this test-case I can freely edit things as I want.

Parsing it programmatically fails with a Null-Pointer-Exception. Why do you do that? So you are not consuming that in the context of a Maven build? Apart from that can you show more of that pom file ?

Maybe it is best to simply write a bug report with stacktrace and a minimal working example. I will then link it here.

It seems like self-referencing properties where not intended to be used by Maven. We can only speculate what the precise intentions of the authors were.
I created a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-8174 with more details about how to reproduce the issue.
